# Cloudflare dynamic dns

Tags: cloudflare

Currently I am using No-Ip for my website and I wanted to use cloudflare for protection against ddos and bots. I noticed that you need a domain for cloudflare. Also I searched the web and found something called cloudflare ddns. I don't own a domain only the dynamic public ip of my home route. So how do I set up cloudflare without a domain?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you will be interested in [Cloudflare Argo Tunnel](https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-free-argo-tunnel-for-your-next-project/).
A single command `cloudflared tunnel --url localhost:80` will expose your webserver running on port 80 on your home server/PC to the internet. Cloudflare will generate a free subdomain under trycloudflare.com domain that your visitors can reach.